# ASP Classic to VB.NET - Recursive Function including RecordSets

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asp-classic, tail-recursion

I'm hoping someone can help me think this one out because I'm stuck.

We are slowly migrating a ASP Classic web site to a .NET web application. I stumbled upon the following function. The function will return an array of strings that consists of hml a-tags.

```
Private Function getFullPathLinks(lNodeId, sPath, sDocTemplate)
    Dim sql, recordSet, rsTmp
    Dim arrPath, sResult
    Dim lDocId

    lDocId  = getDocumentId(lNodeId)

    sql = "SELECT parent_id, label FROM wt_node WHERE (node_id = " & lNodeId & ")"
    Set recordSet = execSqlCache(oConn,sql,Array(),Array("wt_node"))

    If Not (recordSet.Bof And recordSet.Eof) Then

        If sDocTemplate <> "" Then
            sPath = sPath & "|" & "<a href='" & sDocTemplate & "?nodeid=" & lNodeId & "&documentid=" & lDocId & "'>" & recordSet("label") & "</a>"
        Else
            sPath = sPath & "|" & recordSet("label")
        End If


        getFullPathLinks recordSet("parent_id"), sPath
    End If
    recordSet.Close
    Set recordSet = Nothing

    arrPath = arrReverse(Split(sPath,"|"))
    sResult = Join(arrPath,sPathDelimiter)
    If Right(sResult,Len(sPathDelimiter)) = sPathDelimiter Then sResult = Left(sResult,Len(sResult)-Len(sPathDelimiter))

    getFullPathLinks    = sResult

End Function
```

The function calls itself at the end and this will not work well in my .NET implementation where we are using DataReaders to talk to the SQL database.

Could I follow the same structure as above and instead use something else than a DataReader to achieve this?

Comment: Re-write the SQL so that a single data set is returned that includes all the rows you need, then drop the recursive nonsense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what SQL Server version you are using, but have you taken a look at recursive queries in SQL? It is designed to retrieve hierarchical data in a single db call. Take a look:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Thanks! Looking into CTE and recursion on Pluralsight now.

Comment: Glad I could help. How is Pluaralsight? Is it worth the money?

Comment: Oh absolutely! Privately I have been going for the "standard" subscription but I recently convinced my employer to get us all "plus" licenses. :)